# Error when install php5-gd on FreeBSD 8.3(shared library "png.6" does not exist)

Tags: php, linux, freebsd, php-extension, php-gd

I updated php to 5.3. But i cannot install gd extension(on freebsd 8.3)
The error lines:

```
# cd /usr/ports/graphics/php5-gd/
# make install clean
===>   php5-gd-5.3.11 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/phpize - found
===>   php5-gd-5.3.11 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/autoconf-2.69 - found
===>   php5-gd-5.3.11 depends on shared library: freetype.9 - found
===>   php5-gd-5.3.11 depends on shared library: png.6 - not found
===>    Verifying install for png.6 in /usr/ports/graphics/png
===>   Returning to build of php5-gd-5.3.11
Error: shared library "png.6" does not exist
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/php5-gd.
*** Error code 1
Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/php5-gd.
```

I tried update and install png lib

```
# cd /usr/ports/graphics/png/
# make deinstall
# cd make install clean
```

Then i saw:

```
100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 2

Total Test time (real) =  25.96 sec
===>  Installing for png-1.5.10
===>   Generating temporary packing list
===>  Checking if graphics/png already installed
===>   png-1.5.10 is already installed
  You may wish to ``make deinstall'' and install this port again
  by ``make reinstall'' to upgrade it properly.
  If you really wish to overwrite the old port of graphics/png
  without deleting it first, set the variable "FORCE_PKG_REGISTER"
  in your environment or the "make install" command line.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/png.
*** Error code 1
Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/png.
*** Error code 1
Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/php5-gd.
*** Error code 1
Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/php5-gd.
```

If i start with directive FORCE_PKG_REGISTER - '"png.6" does not exist' apears again. I did `portupgrade` - but it did not help too. Any ideas how correctly avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the ldconfig hints files.  Note: /etc/ld.so.conf and /etc/ld-elf.so.conf don't seem do anything on FreeBSD.

Out-of-date hints files errors look like this (when the correct shared lib actually exists):

```
Shared object "libintl.so.8" not found, required by "vim"
```

So, you'll have to run this ugly command:

```
 ldconfig /lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/compat /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/compat /usr/local/lib/compat/pkg /usr/local/lib/graphviz /usr/local/lib/mysql /usr/local/lib/nss /usr/local/lib/pth /usr/local/share
```

Perhaps there's another way to configure ld/ldconfig so that It Just Works.

Answer (score -1):

The name of the shared library for libpng is `/usr/local/lib/libpng15.so.15`, at least on FreeBSD 9.

For some reason php-gd isn't picking that up. Maybe it thinks you're on Linux?

Make sure your ports tree is up to date. The current version of libpng is 1.5.14.

Comment: The php5-extension by default contains gd. But gd couldn't install first time from /usr/ports/lang/php5-extension. And i tried install gd from /usr/ports/graphics/php5-gd. But problem appeared desc above. I installed gd when tried once again reinstall php5-extension. Now everything is ok but i didn't understand exactly what was the bug ))